# Drag and add items to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, treeview

I have a ListView with 3 groups.
I drag an item from TreeView to ListView:

```
private void listViewDemo_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!is_listview) //treeview item
    {
        //get a text of a draged item
        string str = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        //get information about hovered item
        ListViewHitTestInfo hit_info =  listViewDemo.HitTest(listViewDemo.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
        //check position - must be on an item
        if (hit_info.Location == ListViewHitTestLocations.None) return;
        ListViewItem prev_item = hit_info.Item;
        ListViewGroup group = prev_item.Group;
        int idx = prev_item.Index;
        //create a new key
        Guid key = Guid.NewGuid();
        string item_key = key.ToString();
        //create a new item
        //option 1
        group.Items.Add(listViewDemo.Items.Insert(idx,item_key, str, ""));
        //option2
        //group.Items.Insert(idx,listViewDemo.Items.Insert(idx, item_key, str, ""));
    }
}
```

I expect to add an item in place of pointed item, but any option adds element in the end of the group.
How can i add the item in the spot where mouse hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to place the item before the item at the mouse pointer...(this is a bit brute force, but it works).

I also want to note that your original code was finding the index of the hotspot item in the entire list. I added the IndexOf call to get it from the group.

```
            if (!is_listview) //treeview item 
            {
                //get a text of a dragged item 
                string str = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString(); 
                //get information about hovered item 
                ListViewHitTestInfo hit_info = listView1.HitTest(listView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))); 
                //check position - must be on an item 
                if (hit_info.Location == ListViewHitTestLocations.None) return; 
                ListViewItem prev_item = hit_info.Item; 
                ListViewGroup group = prev_item.Group;
                int idx = group.Items.IndexOf(prev_item);
                //create a new key 
                Guid key = Guid.NewGuid(); 
                string item_key = key.ToString(); 
                //create a new item 
                //option 1 
                List<ListViewItem> list = new List<ListViewItem>();
                while(group.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = group.Items[0];
                    listView1.Items.Remove(lvi);
                    list.Add(lvi);
                }

                group.Items.Clear();
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(str, "");
                item.Name = item_key;
                list.Insert(idx, item);
                foreach (ListViewItem i in list)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(i);
                    group.Items.Add(i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: And if i want to add after: list.Insert(idx + 1, item); Just awesome!

Comment: great...seems like it should work given your original code, and in fact, the item goes into the right slot in the group.Items list, but apparently the rendering uses something else to prioritize.

Comment: i bind an object (class) to an item. Like Test test = Test(); and then Item.Tag = test;